# Next.js compilation not reflecting changes in /api/shop/get_product_by_id

Tags: caching, next.js, build, compilation, nextjs-api-router

I'm encountering an issue with Next.js where changes made to the `/api/shop/get_product_by_id` route are not triggering compilation. Even though the log indicates that the `/shop/product/[category]/[product_name]` route has been successfully compiled, the compilation status for the `/api/shop/product/` route does not seem to update as expected.

Here's a snippet from the compilation log:

```
Compiling /shop/product/[category]/[product_name] ...
 ✓ Compiled /shop/product/[category]/[product_name] in 6.7s (470 modules)
 ✓ Compiled in 512ms (243 modules)
 ✓ Compiled in 187ms (227 modules)
```

Sometimes it works, for example if I wait a few minutes and then save the file using ctrl+save it works. It works 100% when I delete the `.next` folder from my project and then run `npm run dev` again, but it is very uncomfortable. Please if anyone know how to solve that problem help me. Thank you.